# Probability that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{X_n}{n}}$ converges where $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of i.i.d with $X_n ~ Unif(-1,1)$

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, random-variables, random-walk, summation-by-parts

> Let $(X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence of indepent random variables all uniformly distributed on $[-1,1]$
>
> Calculate the probability that
>
> $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{X_n}{n}}$$ converges

Using [Kolmogorov's 0-1 law](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_zero%E2%80%93one_law) I know that the probability is either $0$ or $1$. I think that the probability is $1$.

This is my attempt

Using [summation by parts](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts) we get

$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{X_k}{k}} = \frac{S_n}{n} + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{S_k \frac{1}{n(n+1)}}$$

Where $$S_i := X_1 + ... + X_{i-1} + X_i$$

Using the [strong law of large numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers) I get that

$$P\bigg(\lim_{n\to\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n}} = 0\bigg) = 1$$

So basically I can assume that $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{S_n}{n}} = 0$, substituting this in the previous equation gives

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{X_n}{n}} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}}$$

So the probability that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{X_n}{n}}$ converges is the same as the probability that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}}$ converges.

Now clearly if $\limsup_{n \to \infty}{\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}} < +\infty$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{\frac{S_n}{n(n+1)}}$ converges, therefore my idea is to prove that

$$P\bigg(\limsup_{n \to \infty}{\frac{|S_n|}{\sqrt{n}}} < +\infty\bigg) = 1 $$

But I don't know how to do that.

More in general, if $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ is a sequence of strictly positive real numbers such that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}{a_n} < \infty$ then it's sufficient to prove that

$$P\bigg(\limsup_{n \to \infty}{\frac{ |S_n|}{n^2a_n}} < +\infty\bigg) = 1$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The series converges with probability $1$ by a simple application of [Kolmogorov's Three Series Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kolmogorov%27s_three-series_theorem) (take $A = 1$ )